# Pandas dataframe groupby more than one string from a column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, sum, pandas-groupby

some example dataset is as follows

```
  Name      Year        Item    sales_Amount1
  A1            1.2019  Badam     2
  A1.pre        1.2019  Badam     10
  A1.post       1.2019  carrot        8
  N1            1.2019  carrot        10
  A2            1.2019  Badam     10
  G             1.2019  Badam     20
  A3            2.2019  soap          3
  P             2.2019  soap      1
```

I have done basic group by as follows.

```
sum_sales1 = df1.groupby(['Name','Year', 'Item']).agg({'sales_Amount1': 'sum'})
```

Is there a way to group by particular stings like... A1, A1.pre, A1.post and N1 should be grouped together.
Another group would be A2 and G. Another one would be A3 and P. There are about 15 rules to combine strings on column "Name". Is it possible to collate them by strings on Column Name? Thanks.

```
  G1 = A1, A1.pre, A1.post and N1
  G2 = A2 and G
  G3 = A3 and P

  Name        Year    Item  sales_Amount1
  G1          1.2019  Badam        12
  G1          1.2019  carrot       18
  G2          1.2019  Badam        30
  G3          1.2019  soap         4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom function to apply the mapping of Name->Group

```py
def map_group(name):
    if name in ("A1", "A1.pre", "A1.post", "N1"):
        return "G1"
    if name in ("A2", "G"):
        return "G2"
    if name in ("A3", "P"):
        return "G3"

sum_sales1 = (df1.assign(Name=df1["Name"].apply(map_group))
              .groupby(['Name', 'Year', 'Item'])
              .agg({'sales_Amount1': 'sum'})
              .reset_index())
sum_sales1
Out[2]: 
  Name    Year    Item  sales_Amount1
0   G1  1.2019   Badam             12
1   G1  1.2019  carrot             18
2   G2  1.2019   Badam             30
3   G3  2.2019    soap              4
```